# matplotlib draw values on top of graph/image

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting a simple graph but would like to draw all values on top to visualize the values. So how would I go from this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = []
for x in range(0, 8):
    row = []
    for y in range(0, 8):
        row.append(x+y)
    img.append(row)
plt.imshow(img)
```

[image]

**to this:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plt.text does the job:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = []
for x in range(0, 8):
    row = []
    for y in range(0, 8):
        row.append(x+y)
        plt.text(x, y, "X", horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center', color="white")
    img.append(row)
plt.imshow(img)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `plt.text`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = []
for x in range(0, 8):
    row = []
    for y in range(0, 8):
        row.append(x+y)
        plt.text(x, y, x+y, c='w')
    img.append(row)


plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks `c='w'` supposed to be `color='w'` ?

Comment: Either should work, at least in `matplotlib` `3.3`.

Comment: Interesting, I have jupyter with python 3.6 and `2.2.2` for matplotlib, would explain probably why this didn't work.